# Why order of $a$ co-prime to $n$ traverses all factors of carmichael function of $n$? -Is it true?

Tags: number-theory, carmichael-function

I'm recently a bit indulged with basic number theory and investigating in the Carmichael $\lambda(n)$ function, which is defined as the smallest positive number that makes $a^x\equiv\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ true for *every* $a$ co-prime to $n$.

On the other hand, the order of $a$ modulo $n$ (given $a$ is co-prime to $n$) is defined as the smallest number that makes $a^x\equiv1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ true, for the *specific* $a$. Denote order of $a$ modulo $n$ as $\mathrm{ord}_n(a)$, it's obvious that of $\mathrm{ord}_n(a)|\lambda(n)$.

**My problem is**, it seems that the order of all $a$ co-prime to $n$ seems to **traverse** all factors of $\lambda(n)$. That is to say, for every factor of $\lambda(n)$, there exists $a$ co-prime to $n$ whose order equals the factor. Or you can write it more formally:
$$
\{\mathrm{ord}_n(a):\gcd(a,n)=1\}=\{d:d|\lambda(n)\}.
$$
I concluded the conjecture from some numerical calculations based on python, but I have no idea why. How can I prove it?

Comment: If there is a primitive root modulo $n$ then the value of $\lambda(n)$ will be $\varphi(n)$, otherwise it will be smaller.  I believe you'll have $\lambda(n)\mid \varphi(n)$ in general.

Comment: From an understanding of primitive roots, you can reach conclusions about how many $a$ will have each order modulo $n$.

Comment: Thank u! Seems I need to learn something about primitive root.